# Android Developer console error report

Tags: android, google-play

I posted a free app and I've got a couple users who posted a comment saying that the app force closes in google's feedback.  It's got a few hundred downloads in the day it's been up with an 84% retention rate.  Google's error report in the developer's console says it has 0 errors.  I've never had an app that reported any errors in the console. Does it actually work or am I getting fake reports of force closes?  I'm a bit suspicious competitors might be posting the comments, but I don't have any way to confirm that the error reporting google provides does actually work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, the 'Report' button is only available on devices running FroYo (2.2) or later, which is *very* few.

At least I've never seen the ability to report an error upon force close.

I don't think there's any reason to assume your users are lying to you. But it's always a good idea to include something in your app that'll allow for the users to submit an error from within the application.

http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/ddf6863e9a31052f?pli=1

Answer (score 0):

you could use this project http://code.google.com/p/android-remote-stacktrace/ to verify