# How can I get app crash log from Google play console

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services

I have android app, released to *Play Store*. Few users are getting crashes & crash asking them to submit report.

I believe these reports are getting stored in google play store console. I am able to get crash count & related device except crash report. Where can I get all issues log report from console?
Thank you

Comment: use can use Google or firebase crashlytics, Fabric is also great option

Comment: Yeah I can use it for future logs. But I need info about crashes which had happened. Thank you.

Comment: ok you mean on crash , crash message send you to by api ?

Comment: Explicitly I have not implemented it but I believe google store it in console as information of released app.

Comment: So is there any way to get crashes information from console.

Comment: well, I really don't know maybe this will help you,
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3180438/android-developer-console-error-report

Comment: Select an app.
On the left menu, select Android vitals > ANRs & Crashes.
Near the middle of your screen, use the filters to help you find and diagnose issues. Or, select a cluster to get more details about a specific crash or ANR error.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

- Select an app.
- On the left menu, select Android vitals > ANRs & Crashes.
- Near the middle of your screen, use the filters to help you find and diagnose issues.
- Or, select a cluster to get more details about a specific crash or ANR error.

Comment: From crashes and anrs :-com.facebook.react.common.c
Exception com.facebook.react.common.c:
  at com.facebook.react.modules.core.ExceptionsManagerModule.reportException
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke
  at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaMethodWrapper.invoke
  at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaModuleWrapper.invoke
  at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.NativeRunnable.run
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:942)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage     
  I am unable to understand this issue.

Answer (score 19):

In the new Developer Console experience, starting to be active on November 2nd 2020, follow the steps below to see crashes and [**A**ndroid **n**ot **r**esponding (ANR)s](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/vitals/anr) reports:

1. Login to the developer console: https://play.google.com/apps/publish/
2. In the overview select an app
3. Look for the ***Quality*** header on the left menu
4. Select ***Android vitals***
5. Select ***Crashes and ANRs***
6. Change the filter to your needs

---

[image: Android Developer Console Crash logs]

---

You may need to **scroll to the right** to access the crash **details**, as mentioned in the comments.

[image: Android Developer Console crash log details]

Comment: Is there a way to see details on the rashes I am seeing in that list? There is no link behind the record shown.

Comment: Is it capable to log offline crashes when comes to online mode ?

Comment: @sebastian.roibu You might have the same problem as me. Your screen is not wide enough. There is a gray list at the bottom of the error report list, move it to the right, blue arrows will occur next to each report.

Comment: I could not figure that out in time and I was never contempt with the error details. So I added Rollbar to my application. It has a lot more functionality and I like it.... so far.

Comment: Awesome mate!!! I spend an hour but wasn't able to find it... Cheers

Comment: lol thx @JohnT that was it. Had to zoom out a bit...

Answer (score 1):

If you like me are using the new Google Play console, your screen might not be wide enough. There is a gray list at the bottom of the error report list, move it to the right, blue arrows will appear next to each report.